# Product rule for derivatives: one is bounded and the other is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}$, $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded and $g: S \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable at $c \in S$ such that $g^{\prime}(c) = g(c) = 0$.

Show that $h = fg$ is differentiable at $c$ as well.

Attempt:

\begin{align*} 
\lim_{x \to c}\dfrac{f(x)g(x)-f(c)g(c)}{x-c} &= \lim_{x \to c}\dfrac{f(x)g(x)}{x-c}\text{ since }g(c) = 0 \\
&= \lim_{x \to c}\dfrac{f(x)g(x)-f(x)g(c)+f(x)g(c)}{x-c} \\
&= \lim_{x \to c}\dfrac{f(x)[g(x)-g(c)]}{x-c} \\
&\leq\lim_{x \to c} B \dfrac{[g(x)-g(c)]}{x-c} = Bg^{\prime}(c) 
\end{align*}

However, there's a problem here. $\lim_{x \to c}\dfrac{f(x)[g(x)-g(c)]}{x-c}  \leq\lim_{x \to c} B \dfrac{[g(x)-g(c)]}{x-c}$ only applies if both limits exist (hence circular logic). Is there any way I can salvage this proof?

Comment: You should tell us what $S$ is.

Comment: @zhw. Doesn't the first phrase already say what $S$ is ?

Comment: No, it just says $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb R,$ which is weird. It would be clearer to say $S$ is an interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B > 0$ such that $|f(x)| \le B$ for all $x$. Then,

$$\left| \frac{f(x)g(x) - f(c)g(c)}{x - c} \right| = \cdots \le B \left| \frac{g(x) - g(c)}{x -c} \right| = B \left| \frac{g(x) - g(c)}{x -c} - g'(c) \right| < B \epsilon$$

Comment: So in other words, $h^{\prime}(c) = 0$?

Comment: @Clarinetist yes